# SQL - Getting a column from another table to join this query

Tags: sql

I've got the code below which displays the `location_id` and total number of antisocial crimes but I would like to get the `location_name` from a different table called `location_dim` be output as well. I tried to find a way to `UNION` it but couldn't get it to work. Any ideas?

```
SELECT fk5_location_id , COUNT(fk3_crime_id) as TOTAL_ANTISOCIAL_CRIMES
from CRIME_FACT
WHERE fk1_time_id = 3 AND fk3_crime_id = 1 
GROUP BY fk5_location_id;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use `join` to lookup the location name.  The query would probably look like this:

```
SELECT ld.location_name, COUNT(cf.fk3_crime_id) as TOTAL_ANTISOCIAL_CRIMES
from CRIME_FACT cf join
     LOCATION_DIM ld
     on cf.fk5_location_id = ld.location_id
WHERE cf.fk1_time_id = 3 AND cf.fk3_crime_id = 1
GROUP BY ld.location_name;
```

You need to put in the right column names for `ld.location_name` and `ld.location_id`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to find a relationship between the two tables to link a location to crime. that way you could use a "join" and select the fields from each table you are interested in.

I suggest taking a step back and reading up on the fundamentals of relational databases. There are many good books out there which is the perfect place to start.